# Prepare Dell PowerEdge R430 for Software Raid Linux

Tags: raid, boot, dell-poweredge, uefi

I am wondering which settings are recommended for a R430 to run in Software Raid mode. The server is equipped with 4 disks which should run in Raid 1 for the boot/system and Raid 10 for data. However a OpenSuse Leap can install but has problems installing the GRUB2 boot loader, so I am wondering if there is a standard way of prepare a PowerEdge base system, preferable UEFI disabled, what are recommended BIOS settings?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sure the disks are formatted and proceed to start an installation from scratch as the default first, to establish if there is a problem with installing GRUB2 in this configuration. If there was a previous operating system on the boot disk, it may be causing a problem with trying to install GRUB2 and get that to work.

As for the RAID, since you have four disks RAID10 can be used. Or run two RAID1s, a pair for the boot/system and the second pair for the data.